# How can I use the string in a cell as a graph data range?

Tags: graph, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a cell with an auto-generated range formula in google spreadsheet:

```
="working time!A1:"&IF(AND(A22=25,B22>0),"A",C22)&IF(AND(B22<>0,A22=25),C23,"")&"7"
```

which outputs something like:

```
working time!A1:B7
```

or

```
working time!A1:P7
```

Is there a way to use the string in my cell as a data range to create a graph that will update as the string in my cell change?

Comment: I don't know how to use indirect and how can I give a copy of my sheet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDIRECT("working time!A1:"&IF(AND(A22=25,B22>0),"A",C22)&IF(AND(B22<>0,A22=25),C23,)&"7")
```

Comment: Should I add this in my cell or put it in the data range in the graph configuration?

Comment: @lolozemadnessgamer in cell. graph does not support ranges constructed via formulas